# How is a 'select_expr' defined?

Tags: sql, parsing, select, grammar

In the mysql docs for the [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement it shows the following for the syntax:

```
SELECT
    ...
    select_expr [, select_expr] ...
    [FROM table_references]
    ...
```

But it doesn't really talk too rigorously about what exactly a `select_expr` is other than giving a few examples, for example:

- *Each select_expr indicates a column that you want to retrieve. There must be at least one select_expr.*
- *SELECT can also be used to retrieve rows computed without reference to any table. For example:*

  ```
  mysql> SELECT 1 + 1;
          -> 2
  ```

What would be a more formal definition of what a `select_expr` may be, for example, some examples I can think of are:

```
SELECT field...                         // grab a field
SELECT CONCAT(field1, field2, ...)...   // grab a calculated field
SELECT NOW()  ...                       // grab a value that has nothing to do with a field
SELECT (SELECT id FROM othertable)...   // grab a value from a subselect that returns a scalar
```

And of course the latter one can get quite complex, as it can theoretically do arbitrarily many SQL statements within it.

Note the above is using the `mysql` reference manual, but I think this is a general SQL question and any backend can be used to answer the question, as all that I'm aware of (postgres, mysql, mssql, sqlite, oracle) have more or less the same `select_expr` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Bison grammar used to parse mysql statements](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy), a `select_item` (which I think mostly corresponds to `select_expr` in the manual) is [defined as follows](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L9686): (I removed the actions for clarity.)

```
select_item:
          table_wild
        | expr select_alias
```

This production refers to:

```
select_alias:
          /* empty */
        | AS ident
        | AS TEXT_STRING_validated
        | ident
        | TEXT_STRING_validated

table_wild:
          ident '.' '*'
        | ident '.' ident '.' '*'
```

`expr` is essentially what the reference manual calls an expression, and `ident` is one of the various possible ways of writing an column identifier.

The `SELECT` statement includes a `select_list`, which is one or more `select_item`s, as above, or a single `*` wildcard token (which is why the `table_wild` production doesn't include an unaccompanied wildcard token.

So basically, a `select_expr` is

- a wildcard `*`-shortcut, (but if it is just `*`, it must be the only `select_expr` in the list), or
- an `expr`, possibly followed by an optional `AS` and an alias name.

That's just the grammar, though. After the statement is parsed, various semantic validity checks will be made, which might reject certain expressions.

Comment: `That's just the grammar, though. After the statement is parsed, various semantic validity checks will be made, which might reject certain expressions.` -- could you please explain what you mean by that or an example?

Comment: sql.yacc.yy -- first I've seen a 20k line source file...

Comment: I'm no MySQL expert, so I don't have a list off the top of my head. But the sort of restrictions I was thinking about would include, for example, ensuring that column labels are unambiguous, that every function is invoked with the correct number (and possibly type) of argument, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You also need (for example, but not complete by any means):

```
SELECT 1         -- a constant
SELECT *         -- grab all fields from all tables
SELECT table.*   -- grab all fields from a specific table
```

In the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) `1`, `CONCAT(field1, field2, ...)`, `NOW()` and `(SELECT id FROM othertable)` are all lumped together as "expressions":

> The list of select_expr terms comprises the select list that indicates
> which columns to retrieve. Terms specify a column or expression or can
> use *-shorthand

The manual lists all possible forms of expressions in the [Expression Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#expression-syntax) section.